# Angular google maps - timeout and polylines rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm in charge of the development of an AngularJS app which aim is to trace routes made by selected drivers. 
I get the routes from a proxy script i integrated on the backend side of my app and used [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) plugin to render the map and the routes(made using polylines objects).

Everything works but i need to delay the polylines rendering, that is, for each route, i don't want the route to be traced whole immediately but one polyline each 3 seconds, in this way to simulate a point moving in the map.

I tried this(inside the `success` method of the `$http.get` promise) :

```
        var fn = function() {
            //alert(xpath);
            $scope.polylines[0].path.push(xpath);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.paths.length; i++) {
                var p = $scope.paths[i];
                for (var j = 0; j < p.path.length; j++) {
                    xpath = p.path[j];
                    //$scope.polylines[0].path.push(xpath);
                    $timeout(fn, 1000);
                }
         }
```

where `$scope.paths` is a collection of latitude, longitude objects. 
Using the `$timeout` directive in this way doesn't work, if i comment the timeout line and uncomment the line above it works(although all routes are rendered immediately). 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Angular Google Maps are you using? I know 2.0.12 (released 12/15, latest version aotw) had some fixes related to polyline updates. Could you throw together a minimal working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunk](http://plnkr.co/) that demonstrates the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

```
var pushPath = function (path) {
    return function () {
        $scope.polylines[0].path.push(path);
        console.debug('pushed ' + path);
    };
};

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.paths.length; i++) {
    var p = $scope.paths[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < p.path.length; j++) {
        xpath = p.path[j];

        $timeout(pushPath(xpath), 1000);
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rx01zw7YuM64QF90puqR?p=preview

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately doesn't work(i don't see any error but no lines are rendered).